# Where to stay under movement restrictions in Ireland?

Tags: covid-19, ireland

As someone from a country not on the [Green List](https://www.gov.ie/en/publication/8868e-view-the-covid-19-travel-advice-list/) I'd be required to [restrict my movements](https://www2.hse.ie/conditions/coronavirus/managing-coronavirus-at-home/if-you-live-with-someone-who-has-coronavirus.html#restrict) for 14 days after entering Ireland. All sources seem to assume one would stay with relatives or friends, yet I have no such acquaintances in Ireland but would benefit from being in the country for viewing rental properties as I'm starting on a job there in October (albeit likely only after two weeks of not being able to do anything, basically).

Which places could I therefore stay at in this time? Are hotels or hostels open and do they accept guests required to restrict their movements in the first place? Would short-stay rentals be a viable alternative? Are there any other options?

Comment: Guidance seems to indicate that hotels can choose whether or not to accept bookings from travellers required to restrict their movements. See App2, page 32 https://failtecdn.azureedge.net/failteireland/Guidelines-for-Re-opening-Hotels-and-Guesthouses.pdf#32

Comment: Those are quite severe rules for hotels, holy cow! Makes me wonder how many actually choose to provide this kind of service...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.